# I exported the environment variable from entrypoint, but why can't I see it when I printed it in the docker container?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

#### I exported environment variables but cannot check at the container with a command below.

```
docker exec -it {containerID} bash printenv
```

**docker-copose.yml**

```
...
 services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: django
    container_name: django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start
...
```

**Dockerfile**

```
...    
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

**entrypoint**

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

echo >&2 echo !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
echo >&2 echo ${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE}
echo >&2 echo DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

Actually everything works fine.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVNl5.png)

Not just printed nothing and weird.

```
docker exec <container_id> bash -c 'echo "$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"'
```

#### What I am curious about is where is the environment exported by entrypoint? Why can't I check inside the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is correction in issuing docker command. Try below commands

```
docker exec -it {containerID} printenv

docker exec {containerID} bash -c 'echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'
```